# How to launch a jQuery dialog based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu, dialog, selectedindex

I am very new to programming and hope that I can get some assistance with this problem. I have a drop down list of six items on my web page. I would like to open a unique dialog box associated with each drop down option. I do not want to display any of the dialog boxes when the page is opened, but keep them hidden until the user selects an option from the drop down menu. I've given each dialog div a class of "hide-answer" so I can keep them hidden when the page is opened. What I have is displaying the dialog on page refresh, not when the drop down item is selected. I am using jQuery UI.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".hide-answer").dialog({
            autoOpen: false
        });

        var selPermit = document.getElementById("permit");
        if (selPermit.selectedIndex === 1) {
            $("#answer-1").dialog('open');
        }
        else if (selPermit.selectedIndex === 2) {
            $("#answer-2").dialog('open');
        }
        else if (selPermit.selectedIndex === 3) {
            $("#answer-3").dialog('open');
        }
        else if (selPermit.selectedIndex === 4) {
            $("#answer-4").dialog('open');
        }
        else if (selPermit.selectedIndex === 5) {
            $("#answer-5").dialog('open');
        }
        else if (selPermit.selectedIndex === 6) {
            $("#answer-6").dialog('open');
        };

    });
</script>

        <div id="permitForm" class="grouped">
            <h2>Do I Need A Permit?</h2>
            <select name="types" id="permit">
                <option selected="selected" value="">-- select type --</option>
                <option value="First">First</option>
                <option value="Second">Second</option>
                <option value="Third">Third</option>
                <option value="Fourth">Fourth</option>
                <option value="Fifth">Fifth</option>
                <option value="Sixth">Sixth</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="hide-answer" id="answer-1" title="First Condition">
            <p>This is the description of when a first condition is needed.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hide-answer" id="answer-2" title="Second Condition">
            <p>This is the description of when a second condition is needed.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hide-answer" id="answer-3" title="Third Condition">
            <p>This is the description of when a third condition is needed.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hide-answer" id="answer-4" title="Fourth Condition">
            <p>This is the description of when a fourth condition is needed.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hide-answer" id="answer-5" title="Fifth Condition">
            <p>This is the description of when a fifth condition is needed.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hide-answer" id="answer-6" title="Sixth Condition">
            <p>This is the description of when a sixth condition is needed.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is a Fiddle for testing: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pnd51hau/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. First, `.dialog()` is only a feature of JQuery UI. Are you using this in your testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pnd51hau/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="permitForm" class="grouped">
  <h2>Do I Need A Permit?</h2>
  <select name="types" id="permit">
    <option selected="selected" value="">-- select type --</option>
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
    <option value="3">Third</option>
    <option value="4">Fourth</option>
    <option value="5">Fifth</option>
    <option value="6">Sixth</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="hide-answer" id="answer-1" title="First Condition">
  <p>This is the description of when a first condition is needed.</p>
</div>
<div class="hide-answer" id="answer-2" title="Second Condition">
  <p>This is the description of when a second condition is needed.</p>
</div>
<div class="hide-answer" id="answer-3" title="Third Condition">
  <p>This is the description of when a third condition is needed.</p>
</div>
<div class="hide-answer" id="answer-4" title="Fourth Condition">
  <p>This is the description of when a fourth condition is needed.</p>
</div>
<div class="hide-answer" id="answer-5" title="Fifth Condition">
  <p>This is the description of when a fifth condition is needed.</p>
</div>
<div class="hide-answer" id="answer-6" title="Sixth Condition">
  <p>This is the description of when a sixth condition is needed.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**JQuery UI**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hide-answer").dialog({
    autoOpen: false
  });

  $("#permit").change(function() {
    $(".hide-answer").dialog("close");
    var sel = $(this).val();
    console.log("Opening #answer-" + sel);
    $("#answer-" + sel).dialog('open');
  });
});
```

You had not bound anything to an event; therefore, making a selection resulted in no action, or function being executed. The change to the `value` attribute allows us to use that in the selector of the dialog.

You can also make the code smaller:

```
$("#permit").change(function() {
    $("#answer-" + $(this).val()).dialog('open');
  });
});
```

**Edit**

I noticed that you could make a 2nd selection when the current dialog was opened. This caused a cascade of dialogs. To fix, added `$(".hide-answer").dialog("close");` to the `.change()` event. This will ensure they all get closed first and then only open the one that was selected.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I needed

Comment: @js97032 Glad to hear that. I hope that you will want to upvote it as helpful and mark it as the answer.

Comment: I'd like to upvote, but it looks like I'll need a reputation of 15 first. I did mark it as the answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.change()` method to check which option is selected. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".hide-answer").dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    });
    $('#permit').change(function(){
        var option = $('option:selected', this).data('open');
        $('#'+option).dialog('open');
    });
});
```

Your dropdown should look like:

```
<select name="types" id="permit">
        <option selected="selected" value="">-- select type --</option>
        <option value="First" data-open="answer-1">First</option>
        <option value="Second" data-open="answer-2">Second</option>
        <option value="Third" data-open="answer-3">Third</option>
        <option value="Fourth" data-open="answer-4">Fourth</option>
        <option value="Fifth" data-open="answer-5">Fifth</option>
        <option value="Sixth" data-open="answer-6">Sixth</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: You can use `.val()` too to get the selected value. Can also use the `.data()` to get the data from the element.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by others, `dialog()` needs jQuery UI. Anyway you can achieve this simply without jQuery UI, like this:
*(NOTE: corollary, you must use styling to get dialog look like with jQuery UI)*

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  var permit = $('#permit'),
      dialogs = $('.hide-answer');
  permit.change(function() {
    dialogs.hide();
    $('#answer-' + permit.val()).show();
  }).change();
});
</script>
<div id="permitForm" class="grouped">
    <h2>Do I Need A Permit?</h2>
    <select name="types" id="permit">
        <option selected="selected" value="">-- select type --</option>
        <option value="1">First</option>
        <option value="2">Second</option>
        <option value="3">Third</option>
        <option value="4">Fourth</option>
        <option value="5">Fifth</option>
        <option value="6">Sixth</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="hide-answer" id="answer-1" title="First Condition">
    <p>This is the description of when a first condition is needed.</p>
</div>
<div class="hide-answer" id="answer-2" title="Second Condition">
    <p>This is the description of when a second condition is needed.</p>
</div>
<div class="hide-answer" id="answer-3" title="Third Condition">
    <p>This is the description of when a third condition is needed.</p>
</div>
<div class="hide-answer" id="answer-4" title="Fourth Condition">
    <p>This is the description of when a fourth condition is needed.</p>
</div>
<div class="hide-answer" id="answer-5" title="Fifth Condition">
    <p>This is the description of when a fifth condition is needed.</p>
</div>
<div class="hide-answer" id="answer-6" title="Sixth Condition">
    <p>This is the description of when a sixth condition is needed.</p>
</div>
```

Note that I changed the `<option>`s values to digits, which allows to simply address `#answer-X`, where `X` is the option value, and merely doesn't target anything when the "-- select type --" is selected.

Comment: You may want to include that OP would need to add styling to build the Dialog boxes for their UI, otherwise this would simply render the `div` into the existing HTML and not have the look and feel of a dialog box.

Comment: @Twisty. Ooops, din't realize that! My answer was only focused on how to minimize the code for the need. Edited.

Comment: cFreed and your answer does that. OP's use of `.dialog()` made me think that actual dialog boxes were the end goal. Otherwise I see nothing wrong with the answer.